# list append memory error

Tags: python, list

I have `.txt` files, each of them consists one very long line, the program stops at the line `b.append(int(j))` throwing a memory error. I don't understand why the program is giving a memory error because the file is of 2.8 MB and my RAM size is 28GB.

```
if __name__=='__main__':
    path=raw_input("enter file path:")
    image_path=raw_input("enter directory where images are to be stored:")
    count = 0
    for f in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
        print(f)
        file = path+'/'+f
        b = []
        a =[]
        ref =[]
        alt = []

        if (f[:-4] == '0'):
            print('cb1')
            ch = open(file,'r')
            for i in ch:
                b += i.split()
            for j in b:
                b.append(int(j))
            count+=1
            print('cb2')

        elif (f[:-4] == '1'):
            po = open(file,'r')
            for i in po:
                a += i.split()
            for j in a:
                a.append(int(j))
            count+=1

        elif (f[:-4] == '3'):
            re = open(file,'r')
            for i in re:
                ref += i.split()
            count+=1

        elif (f[:-4] == '4'):
            al = open(file,'r')
            for i in al:
                alt += i.split()
            count+=1
        if (count == 4):
            break


    cnt = 0
    for f in sorted(os.listdir(path)):
        print(f)
        file = path+'/'+f
        cnt += 1
        if cnt>4:
            process(path+'/'+f, image_path , f)

    ch.close()
    po.close()
    re.close()
    al.close()
```

I'm using python 2.7 64bit on ubuntu 16.04 with 28 GB RAM. The 0.txt can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13iIYLGnlfGUgi96myRy9gc8YVOrLn4G2/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is not pertaining to your infinite loop issue, but what is the purpose of doing `x[:-4] == c`, where `c` is a string of length 1? The `[:n]` syntax returns a string of one or more characters, and I’m willing to bet that based on the fact that you only ever compare against a single character, that this is not the syntax you want.

Comment: I have files with names `0.txt`, `1.txt` etc `f[:-4] == 0` is to ensure that I'm using `0.txt`

Comment: Ah. That makes sense. I recommend you check out `os.path.splitext(...)` for a slightly more robust solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. My team mate wrote this code, I suggested him to use `os` package. Anyway it seems like I ran into another infinite loop :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have:

```
for j in b:
    b.append(int(j))
```

You are appending items to `b` while iterating over it. This way your list grows indefinitely.

You probably want to do something like `b = [int(j) for j in b]` instead.